# How to use the Microsoft Translator API over Windows Azure, for Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, azure, microsoft-translator

Previously there the bing translator was easily accessible with the SOAP interface. Now it has been migrated to Windows Azure. I have registered in the Azure marketplace for 10000 letters per month (free).  How can I translate text through the translator api, for windows phone in C#? Please help. I am not sure how to use the BeginExecute and EndExecute for queries.

I have downloaded and added the TranslatorContainer.cs to my project. For now I am just trying to get the Languages with the GetLanguagesForTranslation method. This is the code which I have written.

```
public partial class PhonePage1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    public PhonePage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Translator transInstance = new Translator();

    }
    class Translator
    {
        private Uri service_root;
        private TranslatorContainer context;

        public Translator()
        {
            service_root = new Uri("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/");
            context = new TranslatorContainer(service_root);
            context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ID","...........");
            var query = context.GetLanguagesForTranslation();
            query.BeginExecute(OnQueryComplete, query);
        }

        public void OnQueryComplete(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            var query = result as DataServiceQuery<Language>;

            string langstring = "";
            foreach (Language lang in query.EndExecute(result))
            {
                langstring += lang.Code + "\n";
            }
            MessageBox.Show(langstring);
        }
    }
}
```

In OnQueryComplete() the `query` is null even after the assignment. The result has the Properties IsCompleted as true, and statusCode is OK. 
I am not able to figure out how to go about this. Please help. 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help from Bing Translator team I got it working in my Silverlight Application:

1. UseDefaultCredentials needs to be turned off on the proxy
2. On the async callback, you were casting the result to a DSQ, but it’s the result’s AsyncState that needs to be casted. See below.

   ```
   private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       var serviceUri = new Uri("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/");
       var accountKey = "**********************"; // 
       var tcode = new Microsoft.TranslatorContainer(serviceUri);

       tcode.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(accountKey, accountKey);
       tcode.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
       var query = tcode.GetLanguagesForTranslation();
       query.BeginExecute(OnQueryComplete, query);
   }

   public void OnQueryComplete(IAsyncResult result)
   {
       var query = (DataServiceQuery<Microsoft.Language>)result.AsyncState;
       var enumerableLanguages = query.EndExecute(result);
       string langstring = "";
       foreach (Microsoft.Language lang in enumerableLanguages)
       {
           langstring += lang.Code + "\n";
       }
       MessageBox.Show(langstring);
   }
   ```

This way you can use BeginExecute() and BeginEnd() to get Async results.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this should work, but UseDefaultCredentials is a property of which class. Is it supposed to be user defined? It is not part of the TranslatorContainer class which is provided.

Comment: can i catch you on chat online? I want to ask a few things regarding this.

Comment: @Avkash -  I'm getting similar errors as the OP. I am trying to add the line of code that sets the "UseDefaultCredentia‌​ls" to false, but that variable within the TranslatorContainer is not available. Can you please explain? I am working in C# for a local windows application.

Answer (score 2):

I had exact same problem and I was suggested that the issue may be related with the how the Async results are return internally when calling GetLanguagesForTranslation, however I did not dig further and just used Execute() to get the list of Language as below:

```
var serviceUri = new Uri("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/");
var accountKey = "***********************"; // 
var tcode = new TranslatorContainer(serviceUri);
tcode.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(accountKey, accountKey);
var languages = tcode.GetLanguagesForTranslation().Execute().ToArray(); 
foreach (var i in languages)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.Code);
}
```

Not sure if that is what you are looking for but it worked in my case well.

Comment: I can understand what you are saying, but there is no Execute method. Silverlight will allow only async calls, in this case. So, I have to use BeginExecute(), but thats what I am not sure how to use. Please help if you know anything about this.

Comment: Sure, Vignesh, will love to help you. I will try to find some info and add here.. can not say how long it will take but I sure will try to see what I can get for you. Please stay tunes..Thanks!!