# Visual Studio 2010: Unable to add Bing search as a service reference. (DataServiceClientGenerator failed)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, bing, bing-api, service-reference

I am trying to use the Bing Web search API in Visual Studio 2010. 
Following the [migration guide](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/content/developers/ADM_MIGRATION_GUIDE.docx), the first step is to add a service reference to my project.
[image: Add service reference]

But when I click OK...

[image: DataServiceClientGenerator]

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: It looks like an OData feed and I just read the guide I didn't find you have to add a service reference like that. On page 11 you are instructed to download the already build proxy.

Answer (score 2):

You really dont need to add any service reference to your project instead just add System.Data.Services.Client reference and then use the code snippet provided in the documentation or the post below.

I have explained it in details in my following post:
[How to use the Microsoft Translator API over Windows Azure, for Windows Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001438/how-to-use-the-microsoft-translator-api-over-windows-azure-for-windows-phone)